# How to pass a argument (from a Form) to a Model method and return calculation

Tags: python, django, function, arguments

I'm learning Python/Django and I have some trouble understanding how you call/pass argument into Models methods

In my case I take a Decimal input from a Form, pass it to a my model method, and recalculate a new value based on data the Model already has in the Sqlite3 db

and display this to my template

If I remove the variable argument in model method and multiply by a constant directly in the model method, the code works and renders fine in the template

Models:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def n_price(self, newprice):
        n_price = self.price * newprice
        return n_price
```

Form:

```
from django import forms

class MultiForm(forms.Form):
    data = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product
from .forms import MultiForm

def multi(request):
    list = Product.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MultiForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = request.POST.get('model')

    p = Product.n_price()
    p(data) 

    return render(request, 'viewinventory/multi.html', {'form': form, 'list': list, 'data': data})
```

Template

...```

```
    {% block content %}
<h2>New price</h2>
<form method="POST" class="price-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

{% endblock %}

```
    {% for list in list %}
    <div>
 {{ list.name }} {{ list.price }} {{ list.n_price }} </div>
```

{% endfor %}

...```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing form (not a number) to the function which is causing the issue. You need to pass data so change the line `Product.n_price(form)` to `Product.n_price(form.data)` to get the number data from the Namespace form.